# How to remove summery box in magento review form

Tags: magento

I have remove the summery box magento product review form. but when i submit the review it still says "Review summary can't be empty". i thought there is server side validation in magento. 
anyone help me how can i remove the validation for summery box in product review from

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Magento doesn't provide this as a option. But, you can go into template `template/review/form.phtml` and hide displaying summary field and set some value for it:

```
    <li style="display: none">
       <label for="summary_field" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Summary of Your Review') ?></label>
           <div class="input-box">
               <input type="text" name="title" id="summary_field" class="input-text required-entry" value="SOMEVALUE" />
           </div>
   </li>
```

Comment: Thank for giving me the idea, i recommend this method. did not get any problem.

Answer (score 2):

Magento engine uses client site and server site validation for processing any kinds of form. If you want remove this field completely you need to overwrite core functionality. The following steps should help you.

1. To stop server site validation

   - copy the file `app/code/core/Mage/Review/Model/Review.php` to `app/code/local/Mage/Review/Model/Review.php`
   - search the `validate` method in the copied file(around line number 118)
   - see the line `$errors[] = Mage::helper('review')->__('Review summary can\'t be empty');`
   - and comment this line
2. To stop client site validation

   - go to the file `template/review/form.phtml` in your theme folder.
   - and remove/hide displaying summary field

Comment: i already tried this method, after removing the validation from validation.js that cause the error " unable to post the review". i thought must remove the entry from the database..

Comment: i did not mention about `validation.js`.

Comment: $errors[] = Mage::helper('review')->__('Review summary can\'t be empty');